# Javascript create multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I try to create a 4-dimensional array. I fill it dynamically and use content of it in another function. But the content is empty. Is there error below code?

```
    var datas = []; // day number of a week
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            var size = 24*60/timeInterval;
            datas[i] = [];

            for(var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                var size2 = allCoords.length / 2;
                datas[i][j] = [];

                for(var k = 0; k < size2; k++) {
                    datas[i][j][k] = [];
                }
            }
        }
```

I test below example :

```
function foo1()
{
    datas[0][0][0].push(10);
}

function foo2()
 {

     document.getElementByID('result').innerHTML = datas[0][0][0];
 }
```

I see only `,,,,,,,`.

Comment: How are you calling `foo1` and `foo2`, and how often?

Comment: Why does `foo1` only push to `datas[0][0][0]`, do you need that four-dimensional array at all? Please show us your actual code that fills it with content.

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ybf5oo9e/) works for me

Comment: You're better off using `console.log()` than `document.getElementByID('result').innerHTML = ...`. You're just seeing a string representation (of an empty array). The console will be more informative.

Comment: what are the values of timeInterval and allCoords? If they are zero that may be your problem

Comment: @Bergi I use datas[0][0][0] because my code doesn't work. This way, I know that where the datas are.

Comment: @AstraBear I write them on web page but they are not zero.

Comment: I really meant that they may give rise to zero values. Eg if timeInterval>24*60 or the array allCoords size is <2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the principal problem is that you're getting the element where you want to show your result badly using `getElementByID` instead of `getElementById`. Also make sure that your element has `innerHTML` property to write the result, or alternatively use `value`.

I write the follow example using `<textArea id="result"></textArea>` and generating a button which calls `foo1();foo2();` `onClick` an it works for me.

In the sample I use an random value for `timeInterval` and `allCoords.length`.

Note also that you want a 4-dimensional array however you're creating a 3-dimensional.

```js
var timeInterval = 60;
var allCoords = { length : 1};
var datas = []; // day number of a week
    for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            var size = 24*60/timeInterval;
            datas[i] = [];

            for(var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                var size2 = allCoords.length / 2;
                datas[i][j] = [];

                for(var k = 0; k < size2; k++) {
                    datas[i][j][k] = [];
                }
            }
        }


function foo1()
{
    datas[0][0][0].push(10);
}

function foo2()
{
   document.getElementById('result').value = datas[0][0][0];
}
```

```html
<textArea id="result"></textArea>
<input type="button" value="foo" onclick="foo1();foo2();"/>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything when I write on text field and press foo.

Comment: why you write on text area? simply press `foo` which writes the `data[0][0][0]` on the textArea. Which it's your purpouse, isn't it?

Comment: @cyclecyletic anyway I change the property `innerHTML` for `value` so the characters in the textArea will be overwrite `:)`

Comment: ok. :) the code is right, I should look at other part of my code. thanks.